# React big calendar, render component when clicking on an event

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-big-calendar

I would like to render a component next to an event when it is clicked to show more information. Something like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/jOVsE.png

I can use onSelectEvent to create a modal but I have no idea how to put the modal next to the event that was just clicked. I have looked into creating custom events with a popover contained within the event text but there seems to be no way to fire the click event from with in the event and I cannot work out how to do it from onSelectEvent.

Comment: you can use the popover of bootstrap like https://reactstrap.github.io/components/popovers/

Comment: I don't really want to import all the css for one component, thanks for the idea though.

Answer (score 3):

```
import React from 'react';
import { Button, Popover, PopoverHeader, PopoverBody } from 'reactstrap';

export default class Example extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.toggle = this.toggle.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      popoverOpen: false
    };
  }

  toggle() {
    this.setState({
      popoverOpen: !this.state.popoverOpen
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Button id="Popover1" type="button">
          Launch Popover
        </Button>
        <Popover placement="bottom" isOpen={this.state.popoverOpen} target="Popover1" toggle={this.toggle}>
          <PopoverBody>/*Your date picker code goes here*/</PopoverBody>
        </Popover>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

[Check for refrence (reactstrap)](https://reactstrap.github.io/components/popovers/)

Comment: I tried creating a button with an on click but it wouldn't fire. I have noticed that rbc-event rbc-selected gets added to the selected class so was considering hiding showing in the css for the popover. Would rather only render one event rather than hide it with css.

Comment: can you paste your code so that It will get clear to me that what actually you are doing